# Putting my JSON data into my XML templates for a TVOS TVML app

Tags: json, xml, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I have completed a few tutorials for developing **apple TV** apps and I am able to successfully get and parse **JSON** no problem and display it in an **xml** template made within the `Js` file.

I have also made an app using the menu bar to navigate through multiple **XML** templates. Now I need to merge these two and have an app that uses the menu bar to navigate through **XML** templates that have data in them via **JSON**. This is my first time working with both **XML** and **JSON** any help is appreciated.

Comment: So I think I might have a solution for this problem but it is not perfect. I just load an empty template and then use innerHTML to replace the lockup elements with the content.